# Ember data store object not rendering through template

Tags: javascript, templates, serialization, ember.js

I am trying to use ember's store to send requests to the api for data. I am so close to getting it working, but for some reason, the model data doesn't display in the template.

I get a response back from the server which looks like this:

```
artist_profile: {
   alias:"alias",
   bio:"biofda",
   created_at:Tue Nov 22 2016 10:50:27 GMT-0500 (EST),
   location:"location",
   portfolio_link:"link",
   updated_at:Thu Dec 22 2016 20:55:38 GMT-0500 (EST)
}
```

But when it goes through the serializer, it is set on the model like this:

Route model:

```
...
data: {
  alias:"alias",
  bio:"biofda",
  created_at:Tue Nov 22 2016 10:50:27 GMT-0500 (EST),
  location:"location",
  portfolio_link:"link",
  updated_at:Thu Dec 22 2016 20:55:38 GMT-0500 (EST),
},
id:"980190976",
...
```

I think this is why it is not rendering properly on the template. In fact if i debugger into the route and call `this.model.alias`, it is returned as undefined. but if i do `route.get('model').get('alias')`, it returns the alias value.

**Anyone know what I'm doing wrong to prevent the store from properly returning a model that the template can render?**

More code:

Adapter:

```
 export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: CONFIG.API_HOST,
    pathForType() {
      return 'artist_profiles';
    }
  });
```

Serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeSingleResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = { artist_profiles: payload.artist_profile };
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

Model class:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const {
  Model,
  attr,
  belongsTo
} = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  alias: attr('string'),
  bio: attr('string'),
  portfolio_link: attr('string'),
  location: attr('string')
});
```

Route model hook:

```
model() {
  return this.get('store').find('artist-profile', 980190976);
}
```

Template:

```
ARTIST PROFIlE <br>

{{model.alias}}

{{model.bio}}

{{model.location}}
```

Comment: Include `loadTracks` method in `masterService`

Comment: changed model hook

Comment: `find` is private method now. so use `findRecord` instead

Comment: the issue is not that store isn't making the call. i've tried `findRecord` and the model still gets serialized the same way

Answer (score 0):

You can add debugging into your template by adding `{{log}}` to it, for example `{{log model}}`. That will output the model to your console.

When I've had similar problems in the past, it's usually because I'm not processing the model recursively, so maybe try using `firstObject`, e.g. `{{model.firstObject.alias}}`.